# What are the selection parameters for an NPN BJT?

Tags: transistors, bjt, component-selection

I'm building an NPN-based driver circuit for disconnecting my battery level measuring voltage divider when not in use. Here's the circuit:

[image: circuit]

> http://www.microbuilder.eu/Tutorials/Fundamentals/MeasuringBatteryVoltage.aspx

I've gotten fairly familiar with selection parameters for mosfets (gate-source voltages and whatnot), but what parameters should I be looking for when picking Q2? Digikey, as always, has about 100 results for BC817

As a small part 2, what is the purpose of R4 in this circuit? I know for MOSFETs, this is done to manage gate capacitance, is it the same idea here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BC817 is a particular type of transistor, so any variations between suppliers will be minimal.

The requirements for this application are minimal. Since we can assume the battery voltage is less than 20V, the Vceo rating needs only to be 20V.

As to the base resistor- it sets the base current- the base-emitter junction behaves like a diode (around 0.7V drop). Most any ordinary inexpensive transistor you can find will have a beta of more than 40. We don't need the transistor to saturate hard in this case, we only need a voltage of more than (say) 4.5V across the 100K resistor, which implies a minimum collector current of 45uA. If the beta is 40, then the base needs to see about 1.1uA. If we assume the minimum supply voltage for our GPIO is 1.8V * 0.95 and the maximum Vbe is 0.8V, then the maximum base resistor is about 800K, so 2K seems pretty safe, even with a really low voltage drive (20K would be fine too). The lower limit on the base resistor is determined by how much current you want to draw from the GPIO.

The leakage should be well under 10uA under all operating conditions to avoid turning the MOSFET on (only potentially an issue at very high temperatures with modern transistors).

It should be NPN type. Avoid RF transistors and exotic SiGe types, they would probably not misbehave but they're of no help, and may be rated for unusually low voltages.

Pretty much any general purpose switching transistor will work here. 2N3904, 2N4401, BC817, 2SC1815, etc. etc. You can search for the most common type and/or least expensive and it will probably meet all the requirements when you look at the datasheet.

Comment: In this particular circuit, is there any advantage in using an NPN BJT over an N-MOSFET?

Comment: The NPN BJT will be cheaper (and more rugged) than a small logic-level input MOSFET with suitable specs. Aside from that, there's not much difference.

Comment: What does "more rugged" mean in this context?

Comment: Much more difficult to destroy by sloppy ESD procedures.

Answer (score 1):

The R4 is there to limit the base current going into the NPN transistor. Once above the Vbe threshold the base looks pretty much like a forward biased diode to GND and will accept current to higher than is safe for the transistor unless the current flow is limited.

For this application you could use almost any small signal switching transistor. Some popular, and inexpensive, types that would be entirely suitable would be the venerable 2N2222 or the 2N3094.